# How to get the nodePort using fabric8 java api for kubernetes?

Tags: java, json, port, fabric8

I am creating a service in the following way

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Service myService = new ServiceBuilder()
        .withNewMetadata()
        .withName(svcName).addToLabels(svcLabelKey,svcLabelValue)
        .endMetadata()
        .withNewSpec().addToSelector(specSelectorKey, specSelectorValue).withType(svcType)
        .addNewPort()
        .withProtocol(protocol)
        .withPort(port)
        .endPort()
        .endSpec()
        .build();
        client.services().inNamespace(namespace).create(myService);
        return myService;
```

How do I get the nodePort it returns from this json?

```
  {
 "metadata": {
        "name": "my-svc",
        "namespace": "myns",
        "selfLink": "",
        "uid": "6cb0f222-7e57-11e5-96f2-005056976c6f",
        "resourceVersion": "1016121",
        "creationTimestamp": "2015-10-29T16:09:25Z",
        "labels": {
          "name": ""
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "ports": [
          {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 80,
            "targetPort": 80,
            "nodePort": 20430
          }
        ],
        "selector": {
          "name": "p"
        },
        "clusterIP": "10.254.181.34",
        "type": "LoadBalancer",
        "sessionAffinity": "None"
      },
      "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {}
      }
    },
```

Are there examples to fetch teh nodeport after a service is created? I can get the service port but not the node port that is added later after creation

Comment: I logged a ticket - https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/197 -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nodePort` is a property defined inside `io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.ServicePort`.

You can obtain the service instance, like:

```
Service srv = client.services().inNamespace(namespace).withName("myid").get();
```

And then you can access the property like:

```
Integer nodePort = srv.getSpec().getPorts().get(0).getNodePort();
```

The code above, will get the `nodePort` of the first port defined for the service. (see `get(0)`). If you have more ports, you'll have to iterate and pick the port you want.

I hope this helps.